# Debug mode extracted from external file

Tags: c#, xml, debugging

I am just starting with C# so this may seem a pretty noobie question for you.
I have a XML file including several parameters a user can change according his needs. One of these parameters is `DEBUG_MODE` (true or false).

In my application, I'm parsing this XML file and getting the DEBUG_MODE value in a boolean `bDebug = "DEBUG_MODE` value read from XML" .

I am looking for a good way to be able to use this `bDebug` variable in every single class I'm creating in the application. What is the solution to that ?
If I create a new `class test`, do I have to create a constructor with a debug parameter ? Like:

```
bool bDebugMode = false;
public test(bool debug)
{
    bDebugMode = debug;
}

public void MethodA()
{
    /* Do stg */
    if(bDebugMode)
        /* print some debug information */
}
```

**Q:** Isn't there a way to make this debug variable accessible to the entire application instead of doing the method I show above ?

Comment: well you could have a static class with the value populated and have parts of your application use that static class.

Comment: You could consider using interfaces for your classes and write a Debug-Decorator, which holds the debug logic before calling the base functionality. If the boolean is true, wrap the classes with your decorator, if not, use the original class.

Comment: http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/staticmethod-variables.php

Comment: You should avoid littering your code with switches. For example, you shouldn't have to check flags or settings to log different messages, both .NET's diagnostics classes and all logging frameworks use logging levels and configuration to control them.

Comment: Of course, you could do it like @Ahmedilyas mentioned, but... I would suggest you another way of tracing debug information without the need of conditional statements. Take a look at the `System.Diagnostics` namespace... there´s a `Debugger` class providing a `Log` method. It will write to a debugger´s output, if one is attached. With this in place, you could reduce some of the noise you´re adding to your code...

Comment: You can create a test class than have all the other classes inherit the test class.  Put all the debug variables in the test class.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Are you saying that I should avoid to have a "Debug" mode to display specific messages ? I want to use this mode to tell the user more about a problem encountered in the application but if he's not interested because everything is working just fine, I don't want to overload the computer with useless log messages

Comment: It seems that a lot of these comments are inferring a particular usage of your debug variable. The question is actually about having some property that is accessible from anywhere in an application isn't it?

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 actually, making properties accessible from anywhere is not a good idea and should be avoided. In fact, for most scenarios, it' unnecessary.

Comment: Whilst I do agree with you, the OP specifically asked **I am looking for a good way to be able to use this bDebug variable in every single class I'm creating in the application**. My answer is to that question. Also, providing a link to some discussion on this topic would help people understand your position.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I thought the use of a debug variable the way I want to do it was a pretty common operation in an application. Apparently it isn't. In big applications, I find it very useful to have the possibility to have debug messages in order to understand the origin of a problem. To have this debug mode enabled/disabled from a user configuration file seem to be a good idea. How would you do it then if neither static nor singleton methods are good ?

Comment: @DylanAlvaro Just check how [System.Diagnostic.Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) or [log4net](http://www.beefycode.com/post/log4net-tutorial-pt-1-getting-started.aspx) work. You call a logging method with a specific severity (eg Trace.TraceError, log.Info or log.Debug) and define in configuration the minimum severity level to emit. The console is just one of the targets supported by both logging mechanisms. You can have errors sent to the screen *and* debug info sent to a log file, by specifying different severity levels for each target

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on static classes and static properties ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx.

In your case, you could have (I'm using a console app as an example) ...

```
public class Program
{
    public static bool __bDebug = false;
    static void Main()
    {
        //code to get settings from your Xml File
        __bDebug = ValueFromXmlFile;
    }
}

public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        //You can access Program.__bDebug from anywhere in your application
        if (Program.__bDebug == true)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Declaring the `__bDebug` property as static means it can be accessed from anywhere in your application, inside any class and any method.

Comment: This seem to be the easiest way to achieve that There are plenty of solutions and I guess I should read a bit more about static classes/properties. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you want to have something that is accessible from all parts of your application then static is **the** way to go! A lot of the .NET framework is made up of static classes ... so if the guys that wrote the framework use `static`, then so should you! :0)

Comment: .NET doesn't use static classes for settings and configurations. It uses variants of the singleton pattern to *avoid* statics. Static classes make testing hard, replacing the storage mechanism for the settings impossible, introduce threading problems. Even singletons are considered problematic, which is why the framework uses dependency injection instead of singletons

Comment: Agreed, I was merely promoting the use of `static` as a standard language feature. The singleton pattern here ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650316.aspx ... uses the `static` keyword after all :0)

Comment: A feature that shouldn't be used for this case, and only used with extreme caution in the few cases where it may be required.